# Return result invisibly

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I’m trying to return a result (in fact, `NULL`) invisibly from a C++ function via Rcpp. Unfortunately I am unable to find out how to do this. My first attempt was to set `R_Visible` but this global variable is no longer exported; next, I tried calling `do_invisible` (the primitive that `invisible` calls) directly but, likewise, it’s not exported (and to be honest I’m unsure how to call it correctly anyway).

I then went the roundabout way, calling R’s `base::invisible` from Rcpp via an `Rcpp::Function`. My code is now something like this:

```
Rcpp::Function invisible = Rcpp::Environment("package:base")["invisible"];

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP read_value(Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<int>> x, int index) {
    try {
        return Rcpp::wrap(x->at(index));
    } catch (std::out_of_range const&) {
        return invisible(R_NilValue);
    }
}
```

This compiles and executes. Unfortunately, the `invisible` call is simply ignored; when calling the function from R with an invalid index, it prints `NULL`. I would like it to print nothing.

For testing:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<int>> make_xvec() {
    return Rcpp::XPtr<std::vector<int>>{new std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}};
}

/*** R
xv = make_xvec()
read_value(xv, 1)
invisible(read_value(xv, 4)) # Works
read_value(xv, 4)            # Doesn’t work
*/
```

Comment: So, if the index is correct, you want the result to be visible. And if the index is not correct, you want `NULL` to be returned invisibly?

Comment: @F.Privé Precisely.

Comment: I always wrapped such logic on the receiving R side. See my answer for more -- as best as I can tell the provided interface does not let us do what you desire _directly at the C++ level_.  And the interface is a given.  No pony for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm.  "Ultimately" we always get `SEXP .Call(id, SEXP a, SEXP b, ...)` and that ends up (via Rcpp Attributes) with something like

```
R> rqdb::qdbConnect
function () 
{
    .Call(`_rqdb_qdbConnect`)
}
<environment: namespace:rqdb>
R>
```

which when we call it gives us

```
R> qdbConnect()
[1] TRUE
R> invisible(qdbConnect())
R>
```

Can't you just wrap another layer at the R side and call it a day?

I think the key really is that a `void` function is possible, but the default is *something* as the `SEXP`.  And C++ only has `return` so you need R for the `invisible` part.

Comment: “Can't you just wrap another layer at the R side and call it a day?” I hadn’t even thought of that but yes, of course I could. It just feels like it should be unnecessary. Does `.Call` not preserve the visibility status? I don’t know enough about the internals to ascertain this but from my reading of “R Internals”, it should be sufficient to cause `R_Visible` to be unset.

Comment: I think the deeper issue is that you want conditional behaviour expressed over one _unconditional fixed interface_ so I am not so sure you can.  Study _Writing R Extensions_, methinks there is no _added_ constraint coming from Rcpp here.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the issue is unlikely to arise from Rcpp. The *conditional behaviour* shouldn’t pose a problem — it works if the code is pure R.